# Fever Chart in FusionCharts

Tags: charts, fusioncharts

Is it possible to make a fever chart using FusionCharts ?

I am trying to make a Scatter chart with diagonal lines, but i need to paint the background, and i couldn't find any way to do that.

Also, the chart background can't be an image, because the drawing may change (n possibilities)

If you know any other way to do that, let me know!

Fever Chart example:
[image: Fever Chart:]

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this using FusionCharts ?

http://jsfiddle.net/subramaniashiva/wzcujwmr/

You can use the **canvasBgColor** attribute and configure the color you want. You can also change this attribute dynamically depending upon your requirement using [this](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/tutorial-how-to-guides-change-chart-properties-at-runtime.html)

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var visitChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'line',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '500',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        containerBackgroundOpacity: "0",
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "xAxisName": "% of duration consumed",
                "yAxisName": "% of duration buffer consumed",

                //Cosmetics
                "lineThickness" : "2",
                "baseFont" : "Helvetica Neue,Arial",
                "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                "showBorder" : "0",
                "showShadow" : "0",
                "showValues": "0",
                "canvasBorderAlpha" : "0",
                "divlineAlpha" : "100",
                "divlineColor" : "#000000",
                "divlineThickness" : "1",
                "divLineIsDashed" : "1",
                "divLineDashLen" : "1",
                "divLineGapLen" : "1",
                "lineColor": "#000000",
                "showXAxisLine" : "0",
                "showAlternateHGridColor" : "0",
                "anchorRadius": "0",
                "numberSuffix": "%",
                "canvasBgColor": "#FF0000,#FFFF00,#00AF50",
                "canvasBgAlpha": "100,100,100",
                "canvasBgAngle": "45",
                "canvasBgRatio": "10,50,40"
            },
            "data": [
                {
                    "label": "0%",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "label": "10%",
                    "value": "8"
                },
                {
                    "label": "20%",
                    "value": "16"
                },
                {
                    "label": "30%",
                    "value": "29"
                },
                {
                    "label": "40%",
                    "value": "35"
                },
                {
                    "label": "50%",
                    "value": "42"
                },
                {
                    "label": "60%",
                    "value": "57"
                }
            ]
        }
    });

    visitChart.render();
});
```

Comment: We already did that with HTML5 using canvas, but I'm sending this to the responsible developer, so he can study other possibilities. Thank you so much!